# How to hook requests in Apache, run a script to validate session cookies and redirect to login if fail

Tags: apache, perl, mod-rewrite, cookies, mod-python

My problem:

1. I have a simple website running with Apache, static HTML and some Perl scripts.
2. Now, I have to add login and password protection.
3. Users will login in an external server (in the same HTTP domain) and that server will set a cookie with some values signed with md5.

How can I hook every request in Apache and execute a script (middleware) that:

- If cookie pass validation, forward the request.
- If cookie not exists or fail md5 verification, redirect to login server.

I'd like to do this with `mod_rewrite`, but I could not find a way to execute a script. May be with `mod_perl` or `mod_python` but not sure with the idea of injecting a Perl/Python interpreter in Apache for this task, seems a bit overkill.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.